# ERR_TIMED_OUT after https configuration

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ubuntu-20.04

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

I have been trying to configure one of my website with HTTPS like I've done multiple times, but it seems like I can't make it work this time.

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 server with Apache 2.4.41 with several sites, but I only want one with HTTPS.

The problem I have is that my website is inaccessible through a browser using HTTPS (It still works in HTTP because I didn't redirect, see the configuration file below) : Firefox returns a PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR and Chrome an ERR_TIMED_OUT error.

I don't think the SSL certificate is the problem, but I first tried to obtain it through Certbot. Since it's not a production server, I thought I could go with a self-signed one, but it didn't solve anything.

Using the self-signed certificate, Apache first logged the following messages :

```
[Wed Nov 03 11:51:46.324941 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 127203] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate! [subject: emailAddress=email,CN=my-site.com,OU=something,O=something,L=somewhere,ST=somewhere,C=XX / issuer: emailAddress=email,CN=my-site.comOU=something,O=something,L=somewhere,ST=somewhere,C=XX / serial: 1FB2B8A5C1E04B87F4B7369B5BDB6EED57E95545 / notbefore: Nov  3 11:44:48 2021 GMT / notafter: Nov  3 11:44:48 2022 GMT]
[Wed Nov 03 11:51:46.324947 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 127203] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate my-site.com:443:0 for stapling
```

After setting SSLUseStapling to off in the relevant Apache configuration file, no error was returned anymore. My website is still inaccessible, though.

Here is the Apache virtualhost configuration file for the concerned website :

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my-site.com
        DocumentRoot "/path/to/webroot"
        <Directory "/path/to/webroot">
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.my-site.com.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.my-site.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName my-site.com
        ServerAdmin email@my-site.com
        DocumentRoot "/path/to/webroot"

        <Directory "/path/to/webroot">
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/certificates/my-site.com/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/certificates/my-site.com/private.key

        SSLUseStapling off

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.my-site.com.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.my-site.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the Apache ssl configuration :

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling off
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"

SSLSessionTickets Off
```

apachectl -t returns no syntax error.

I enabled the relevant rules in my firewall, and the apache ssl module is also enabled.

Any idea why this doesn't work ?

Thanks again !

Comment: *"I enabled the relevant rules in my firewall"* - the problem description looks like a firewall issue. I suggest that either the firewall was not sufficiently disabled (incomplete  or wrong configuration) or that there are additional firewalls outside the local setup, as often the case in cloud environments.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm not in the cloud. The server is a computer I set up myself behind a static IP at my place lol. I checked after seeing your message and, of course, the port 443 is closed on my router ... I feel dumb, sorry and thanks for your time !